# Linear operator on $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\ell^2$ denote the space of all square-summable real sequences.

Let $\{c_k\}$ be a fixed sequence of real numbers. Define an operator $D$ on $\ell^2$ by $D\{x_k\} = \{c_kx_k\}$.

Suppose that $D$ is a well-defined operator mapping $\ell^2$ into $\ell^2$ continuously. Prove that $\sup_k c_k$ is finite.

I have tried to prove this but every time I try I end up with inequalities pointing in the wrong direction and it doesn't help.

I don't want a proof, but I would like a hint or two if possible.

Comment: $l^2$ corresponds  to square-summable real sequences, right?

Comment: yeah that's correct

Comment: Thank you for the early response. Your hint is that continuity is equivalent to boundedness in a Hilbert space (which $l^2$ is). In other words, there is a constant $M$ such that $\sum c_k^2 x_k^2 \leq M\sum x_k^2$  for all $x_k \in l^2$. Now, you can probably finish it.

Comment: I see the doubt in an answer below. Let $\{s_k\}$ correspond to the sequence $0,0,...,1,0,0,...$, where the $1$ is at the $k$th position. Now, can you finish it?

Comment: Yeah I've got it now, thanks a lot. It's so simple lol.

Comment: Sometimes simple questions appear difficult because the one key point goes missing from routine analysis. You are welcome.